# Let external container know about subnets created by multiple docker-compose projects

Tags: docker-compose

I have a multi-client setup, each client having similar application stack. To simplify it a bit, let's say a typical tomcat web app working on a db.

Clients must be completely isolated from each other, each with their on application stack, including a standalone tomcat).

`VirtualHost` configurations on httpd map domains to the corresponding tomcat instance via AJP. 
For example:

```
client1.example.com -> 172.18.0.2:8009
client2.example.com -> 172.19.0.2:8009
```

I found `docker-compose` very useful within each client. One of the things I like is that it even takes care of creating private subnets for each client and containers within that client don't even need to know other containers' IP address, but can use aliases that are automatically set up by the `links` configuration.  Pretty neat.

```
httpd
clients
  client1
    docker-compose.yml
    tomcat
    db
  client2
    docker-compose.yml
    tomcat
    db
```

Now the problem. httpd (which I would also want to dockerize) needs to reach tomcat for all clients. However, it doesn't know their IP.

How can I realize this mapping in `VirtualHost`? I.e. how to solve the question marks below?

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName client1.example.com
  ..
  ProxyPass / ajp://?????:8009/
  ..
</VirtualHost>
```

One thing I have tried is to have some global env file, with all subnets and IPs explicit, like:

```
CLIENT1_TOMCAT=172.18.0.2
CLIENT2_TOMCAT=172.19.0.2
```

and use this in both each client's yml and httpd yml. 
That's pretty ugly though, because custom IP configuration within a yml is either for all or for no service. I was hoping I could set the one for tomcat and let the others automatic, but they end up overlapping. All the sudden, specifying IP configurations for all services and all clients, makes the whole thing a lot less elegant.

I also know it is possible to inspect a container's IP like this:

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' client1_tomcat
```

However, this requires the container to exist already. Also, if I use this method then I have to modify httpd's configuration every time the container is recreated, as it may change IPs.

I guess that somehow I wold like httpd's yml to "include" the clients' ones, so that it can know about their subnets. Still, keeping clients' subnets separated.

Any idea how I should approach this?

**UPDATE**
working setup based on @tcnj's answer:

Content of `httpd/docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'

services:

  httpd:
    image: httpd
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    ..
    networks:
      - client1_default
      - client2_default
    external_links:
      - client1_tomcat_1
      - client2_tomcat_1

networks:
  client1_default:
    external: true
  client2_default:
    external: true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to solve your problem is to put httpd on *all* of the client networks, and then refer to the tomcat containers by their name.

Eg:

You have client1 with network client1_default, and with the container client1_tomcat.
You also have client2 with network client2_default, and with the container client2_tomcat.

If you're starting httpd from the command line then you can add `--network client1_default --network client2_default` as extra options to `docker run` before the image name. If you're using docker compose for httpd as well then you can use the following:

```
httpd:
  ...
  networks:
  - client1_default
  - client2_default
  ...
```

In your httpd config you can then have:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName client1.example.com
  ...
  ProxyPass / ajp://client1_tomcat:8009/
  ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName client2.example.com
  ...
  ProxyPass / ajp://client2_tomcat:8009/
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Yes, this is the right approach! For completeness, as far as I could find out: 1) the networks need to be declared at top-level as `external`, so they won't be recreated, and then also used inside the httpd service as you did; 2) in order to use aliases, like `client1_tomcat`, the httpd service also needs to declare them as `external_links`.